# Matrix version of subgraph isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Matrix theoretic framework to capture graph isomorphism between two graphs $G1$ and $G2$ with adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ respectively is given by $G1\cong G2\iff\exists\mbox{ }\mathsf{permutation }\mbox{ }\mathsf{matrix}\mbox{ }P:A=PBP'$.

Is there a better matrix theoretic framework to capture subgraph isomorphism between two graphs $G1$ and $G2$ with adjacency matrices $A$ and $B$ than
$G1\leq G2\iff\exists\mbox{ }\mathsf{permutation }\mbox{ }\mathsf{matrix}\mbox{ }P,\mathsf{projection}\mbox{ }\mathsf{matrices}\mbox{ }Q,R:A=PQBRP'$?

Here assume the word $\mathsf{projection}$ means only some columns or rows are selected from $B$ so that $Q,R$ are rectangular and $QBR$ is a smaller square matrix of size compatible with $A$.

Comment: The reoccurrence of $A$ and $B$ in the subgraph part looks confusing...

Comment: @MorganRodgers really?

Comment: @MorganRodgers It is implicityly assume $P,Q,R$ are of compatible sizes. For example $Q,R$ are rectangular.

Comment: @MorganRodgers updated

Comment: @MorganRodgers do you have a suggestion? $Q$ and $R$ are not really identity

Comment: @MorganRodgers Identity is not rectangular.

Answer (score 1):

To appropriately single out a subgraph of $G_{2}$, you are looking at forming $QBR$. The "selecting only some rows or columns" requirement means you need $Q$ and $R$ to be, essentially, copies of $I_{n}$ with some rows/columns removed (remove the rows of $Q$/columns of $R$ corresponding to the rows/columns you want to remove from $B$). You also have to take the same rows as columns (since they correspond to vertices) so $Q = R^{T}$. Also note that this will only give **induced** subgraphs.

I don't know about a better matrix theoretic framework.  It depends on what you are trying to do.  In practice, you definitely wouldn't want to model your permutations as matrices (or your row/column selection operations), since matrix multiplication is way more computationally intensive than just applying permutations.

Comment: What is an induced subgraph? Does matrix model give only induced subgraph? Is there something it does not give? Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Consider $K_{4}$, the complete graph on 4 vertices.  A path of length $2$ is not an induced subgraph, because if you take any 3 vertices they form a triangle.